# NodeJS Nested group aggregation with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a data set of payments that I want to group together to show on page in a report form. Below is the data:-

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bed91bfbbcf4d0014ec3ab1"
},
"type": "Card",
"reason": "Deposit",
"item": "Dress",
"amount": 100,
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bed91bfbbcf4d0014ec3ab2"
},
"type": "Cash",
"reason": "Deposit",
"item": "Dress",
"amount": 400,
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bed91bfbbcf4d0014ec3ab3"
},
"type": "Cash",
"reason": "Deposit",
"item": "Dress",
"amount": 100,
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bed91bfbbcf4d0014ec3ab4"
},
"type": "Cash",
"reason": "Full Balance",
"item": "Dress",
"amount": 200,
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bed91bfbbcf4d0014ec3ab5"
},
"type": "Card",
"reason": "Full Balance",
"item": "Dress",
"amount": 300,
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bed91bfbbcf4d0014ec3ab6"
},
"type": "Cash",
"reason": "Deposit",
"item": "Jacket",
"amount": 400,
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bed91bfbbcf4d0014ec3ab7"
},
"type": "Card",
"reason": "Deposit",
"item": "Jacket",
"amount": 150,
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bed91bfbbcf4d0014ec3ab8"
},
"type": "Cash",
"reason": "Full Balance",
"item": "Jacket",
"amount": 250,
},
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5bed91bfbbcf4d0014ec3ab9"
},
"type": "Card",
"reason": "Full Balance",
"item": "Jacket",
"amount": 350,
}
```

I can group the data by 1 item without problem, so for example I can group and total the amounts by item (Dress, Jacket etc.)

I would like to group by all three fields so would get an output that looks like this and structured so I can display them on the Frontend.

```
{
Dress: {
    reason: {
        "Deposit" : {
            type: {
                "Cash": 500 //Combination of 2 records for example
                "Card": 100
            }
        }
        "Full Balance" : {
            type: {
                "Cash": 200
                "Card": 300
            }
        }
    }
}
Jacket: {
    reason: {
        "Deposit" : {
            type: {
                "Cash": 400
                "Card": 150
            }
        }
        "Full Balance" : {
            type: {
                "Cash": 250
                "Card": 350
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I attempted to start this but I am struggling to get the concept right to be able to produce the right data. Obviously this doesn't produce the right output.

```
$group: {
        _id: {item: "$item"},
        totalAmount: {$sum: "$amount"}
    },
    $group: {
        _id: {item: "$_id.item"},
        total: {
            "$push": {
                type: {type: "$type"},
                amount: {$sum : "$amount"}
            }
        }

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't find any logic in your example . are you sure it's with the right numbers ? 
the numbers don't add up.

Comment: @Mazki516 the numbers are just by example. The example sets are only a snippet of the data and I just wanted to demonstrate the possible outcomes without attaching huge datasets. Essentially the logic would look like this:- Group all of the Items (Dress, Jacket etc), THEN in those groups, group them all by payment 'reason'. Finally then group and total those by type of payment (Card, cash etc.)

Comment: In order for someone to help you , we need to understand the full logic . please post an example where you list **all** records .   these 3 records you gave as an example are just not enough to see the full picture

Comment: OK @Mazki516 I have added a full example dataset which will add up to the amounts shown in the output. Any more questions, please ask. Thank you

Comment: Can there be more `type` rather then `Card` and `Cash`?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, yes there could be a few more options for each of the 3 fields